# How to read integer from InputStremReader

Tags: java, char, int, inputstreamreader

I'm a beginner... please bear with me :)

This is a code that supposedly reads 10 integers in an array. The `InputStreamReader` reads in char (that what java Docs said) how to convert the char into int to be saved in the array?

```
int[] array = new int[10];
System.out.println("Please enter 10 integers. ");
for(int x=1; x <11; x++){
    InputStreamReader keyboard = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    // Change char into int   
    array[x] = keyboard;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @SJuan76, Beside that your comment is rude. Google do not provide exact asnwer to the OP questions in first 10 resulst. Instead of that you could provide a link to tutorial how to use Scanner class or something. Everyone once was a beginner.

Comment: @Vash everyone once was a beginner, but some put more effort to it than others to stop being one. Not googling it for at least five minutes is the bare minimum, if someone does not care about it I do not care about seeming to be rude.

Comment: @SJuan76 I was socked by your answer at first but I appreciate your reply anyway... you're absolutely right about putting more effort to it... I'll work on that ... thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] array = new int[10];
for(int x=0; x <10; x++){
    array[x] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

`Scanner#nextInt` scans the next token of the input as an `int`. And throws

```
InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed
```